# Datagridview direct editing

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a dataGridView which has 2 rows(2 products). Only 1 column is editable(quantity). Now I don't know how to save just 1 row's data, in case I don't put quantity on the either one of the product. I'm using C# and SQL server

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: You could loop thru each row and perform a save if the row has a quantity > 0.  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)  { if (row.Cells["quantity"].Value > 0 ) save(row) }